# How can you disable a button if data ID exists in local storage object?

Tags: javascript, click, angular6, local-storage

I am trying to prevent multiple votes of the same question on a component when a user clicks yes or no.

I have stored the user's response in local storage into an Object Array. I need to find a way to check if that object ID exists in local storage and thus, disable it so to stop the user voting for the same thing over and over and over again.

I have tried to place a boolean on the button so... [disabled]="disabled", but when the user navigates and returns, the button is active again.

**poll-item.component.ts**

This is the example of the 'No' vote click event:

```
VoteNo() {
    const newVote = {
      id: this.poll.id,
      poll_title: this.poll.poll_title,
      poll_question: this.poll.poll_question,
      yes: this.poll.yes,
      no: this.poll.no + 1
    }
    this.pollsService.updatePoll(this.poll.id, newVote)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (localStorage) {
            var userVotes;
            if (!localStorage['userVotes']) userVotes = [];
            else userVotes = JSON.parse(localStorage['userVotes']);
            if (!(userVotes instanceof Array)) userVotes = [];
            userVotes.push(newVote);
            localStorage.setItem('userVotes', JSON.stringify(userVotes));
          }
          this.getPolls.emit(response);
        }
      )
  }
```

**poll-item.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="config">
  <ng-container *ngIf="poll">
    <span class="poll_header_wrapper">
      <div class="poll_icon">
        <img src="../../../../assets/img/poll_icon.svg">
      </div>
      <div class="poll_title">
        <h5>{{ poll.poll_title }}</h5>
      </div>
    </span>
    <div class="question_buffer">
      <p>
        <small>{{ poll.poll_question }}</small>
      </p>
    </div>
    <span class="results">
      <p><small>
          <h4 *ngFor="let config of config"
            [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(to right, #' + config.primary_color.data.hex_code + ' ' + percentage(poll.yes, [ poll.yes + poll.no ]) + '%' + ', #' + config.secondary_color.data.hex_code  + ')'}">
            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> {{ percentage(poll.yes, [ poll.yes + poll.no ]) }} %</h4>
        </small></p>
      <p><small>
          <h4 *ngFor="let config of config"
            [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(to right, #' + config.primary_color.data.hex_code + ' ' + percentage(poll.no, [ poll.yes + poll.no ]) + '%' + ', #' + config.secondary_color.data.hex_code  + ')'}">
            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> {{ percentage(poll.no, [ poll.yes + poll.no ]) }} %</h4>
        </small>
      </p>
    </span>
    <p class="totals"><small>Total: {{ getTotalVotes(poll.yes, poll.no) }} Votes</small></p>
    <div class="voting_buttons">
        <button (click)="voteYes(poll)" **[disabled]="disabled"**><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
        <button (click)="VoteNo(poll)" **[disabled]="disabled"**><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**[disabled]="disabled"** - this doesn't work, but could potentially by checking if id in local storage is true. I just don't know the best way to write it.

What I would like to know is how once the request has been sent to local storage, can I then run a check of the local storage array find the IDs that have been voted on and disable them? So the user can't vote yes and no multiple times for the same question.

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: I do not use angular but should you not call some of the code in updatePoll on load of the page?

Comment: that's an idea, then set disabled if the votes have been made. I'll have a look. :)

Comment: Where you have defined the variable `disabled`. For using value within square bracket, the variable must be declared in .ts file